# Group(s) around a word

Tags: regex

I request your help. I've been trying to get a specific regex to work but I can't get it to do what I need.

The regex will group anything around **[test]**, not itself.
For example,

```
Input: [{1,/;k1`\n\t[test]|}[{3\n\t,/[test;k1`\n\t[test][test]|}[{9\n\t,/;s2`\t\n{...}
Output: 
        Group 1: [{1,/;k1`\n\t
        Group 2: |}[{3\n\t,/[test;k1`\n\t
        Group 3: 
        Group 4: |}[{9\n\t,/;s2`\t\n
        Group n: {...}
```

Also works without it

```
Input: [{1,/;k1[tes]`\n\t
Output: 
       Group 1: [{1,/;k1[tes]`\n\t
```

*Note: regex uses Expression Flags: /ig

Comment: Can you add the regex you currently have?

Comment: [^\[]*(?:\[(?!test\])[^\[]*)+/ig, but it is wrong.

Comment: Instead of grouping I suggest using `Split`. Simply split on `\[test]`, then you get an array with the content between `[test]`.

Comment: @Alex If you don't mind getting your matches from the capture groups, you could also use alternation. For example: `(.*?)\[test\]|(.+)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's the PCRE regex engine then you can use `\K` to ignore the `[test]`

Then it just needs a lookahead for whatever else comes before `[test]` or the end of the string.

```
\[test\]\K|([\s\S]*?)(?=\[test\]|$)
```

In javascript you could capture what's not `[test]`

```
let re = /(?:\[test\]|^)([\s\S]*?)(?=\[test\]|$)/ig;
let match;
while ((match = re.exec(Input)) !== null) {
  console.log(match[1]+'\n')
}
```

But to be fair, simply splitting the string on `[test]` seems also an option.

Comment: Hi, it work fine, but I have a problem that my javascript is not support lookbehind (?<=). Do you have any other way?

Comment: @Alex Javascript? Split it.  `Input.split(/\[test\]/i)`

Comment: Yes, I did with split, but not working with a (too) large string.  So that I try to use regex.

Comment: I'm intending to use regex to match and "while" to work with each group.

Comment: Then do something with the capture group. See update.